# Limit of $\lim_{n\rightarrow∞} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{(n+k)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

What is the limit of $\lim_{n\rightarrow∞} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{(n+k)^2}$? I got lower bound by plugging  $k=n$ which results in limit equal to $1/4$. Similarly, the upper bound is 1, for $k=0$. I do not really know how to proceed, so I would appreciate a hint, I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Comment: I think an integral approximation of $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{(n+k)^2}
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(1+k/n)^2}$ may help.

Comment: This was from a calculus text?  And was there an example computed just before this using Riemann sums to evaluate a limit like this?

Comment: No, I am preparing for calculus test and its example from past exam. We have not studied integrals yet, so the solution probably involves something rather simple (comparison test, squeeze theorem etc.)

Comment: Sedrakyan's inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedrakyan%27s_inequality gets you $(\ln 2)^2 \approx 0.480 $ as a lower bound, but I don't know how to improve upon this lower bound. And finding a good upper bound seems even more difficult...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to do it without integrals?  Here is one way.  But of course the method shown by Nevzat is much simpler.

Upper bound
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{(n+k)^2} &< \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{(n+k)(n+k-1)}
\\ &=
\sum_{k=1}^n \left[\frac{k}{n+k} - \frac{k-1}{n+k-1}\right]
\\ &=
\frac{n}{n+n} - \frac{0}{n+0}\qquad\text{(telescoping sum)}
\\ &= \frac{1}{2} .
\end{align}
Lower bound
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{(n+k)^2} &> \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{(n+k+1)(n+k)}
\\ &=
\sum_{k=1}^n \left[\frac{k+1}{n+k+1} - \frac{k}{n+k}\right]
\\ &=
\frac{n+1}{n+n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1}\qquad\text{(telescoping sum)}
\\ &= 
\frac{n^2}{(2n+1)(n+1)} .
\end{align}
So
$$
\frac{n^2}{(2n+1)(n+1)} < \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{(n+k)^2} < \frac{1}{2} ,
\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{(2n+1)(n+1)} 
\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{(n+k)^2} 
\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2} ,
\\
\frac{1}{2}
\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{(n+k)^2} 
\le \frac{1}{2} .
$$

Comment: +1 very nice...

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{(n+k)^2}= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(1+\frac{k}{n})^2}=\int_{0}^1\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}=\frac12$$

Comment: Thanks for correction